# Can't read file and store in data members of struct

Tags: c++, input, struct, fstream

This is for an assignment so I'm following assignment guidelines of the desired struct layout as well as the overloads. Trying to get my program to read each line and assign each line to the variable.

The text file looks like:

```
John 

S

Maggey

G
```

and my code looks like:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
namespace
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int allocated = 0;
}

//====================================================================
struct student
{
    char *firstname;
    char lastname;
    int studentId;
    int occupied;

    student() : lastname(0), studentId(0), occupied(0)
    {
        firstname = new char[64];
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
            firstname[i] = 0;
    }

    student(int s)
    {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Allocated: " << allocated << std::endl;
        int currentLoc = allocated;
        allocated += s;
        firstname = new (&buffer[currentLoc]) char[s];
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
            firstname[i] = 0;
    }

    void *operator new(size_t s)
    {
        std::cout << "Operator new allocated: " << allocated << std::endl;
        int currentLoc = allocated;
        allocated += s;
        return &buffer[currentLoc];
    }

    void student::operator delete(void *ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Delete called " << std::endl;
        std::free(ptr);
    }

    student::~student()
    {
    }
};

//====================================================================
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    student *studentLoader = new student[25];

    std::fstream fin;
    fin.open("students.txt");
    char ln;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        fin.getline(studentLoader[i].firstname, 99);
        fin.getline(ln, 64);
        studentLoader[i].lastname = ln;
        studentLoader[i].studentId = (rand() % (9999 - 999)) + 999;
        studentLoader[i].occupied = 1;
        if ((i % 10) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "First name: " << studentLoader[i].firstname << " Last initial: " << studentLoader[i].lastname << " ID: " << studentLoader[i].studentId << std::endl;
            delete[] studentLoader;
        }
    }
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried doing :

```
    std::fstream fin;
    fin.open("students.txt");
    char ln;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
    {
        fin.getline(studentLoader[i].firstname, 99);
        fin.getline(studentLoader[i].lastname, 99);
        studentLoader[i].lastname = ln;
        studentLoader[i].studentId = (rand() % (9999 - 999)) + 999;
        studentLoader[i].occupied = 1;
        if ((i % 10) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "First name: " << studentLoader[i].firstname << " Last initial: " << studentLoader[i].lastname << " ID: " << studentLoader[i].studentId << std::endl;
            delete[] studentLoader;
        }
    }
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

But would receive an error for the second attempt to getline.

When trying

```
fin >> studentLoader[i].firstname;
```

nothing would be inserted into the variables.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char*` please. Also no `new` `delete` please.

Comment: You should [simplify your program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and remove any unnecessary code (like the `new` and `delete` overloaded operators).

Comment: It's for an assignment so I'm following the requirements. We're required to overload those operators as well as use the char*.

Comment: You can start by indenting your code sensibly, so that it is actually readable.

Comment: Edited to look better, added clarification as to why i'm using char* and overloading the new and delete operators.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a char, a pointer to a char, and an array of chars?

Comment: I think you made a typo in your sample, both firstname and lastname are `char*`, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not a typo and you really wanted to use single character for the `lastname` you should read it as a single character as well:
`fin >> studentLoader[i].lastname >> std::ws`.

Also consider reading [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) for the functions and classes you are using. This is generally good habit and will save you from fair amount of failures.

Answer (score 0):

By slightly modifying you `struct student` by changing the type of `firstname` and `lastname` to `std::string`, you won't have to dynamically allocate / deallocate memory and you will reduce the code by half.

For example, you could define it as:

```
struct student {

    // constructor
    student (std::stirng fn, std::stirng ln, int ID, int oc) 
       :  firstname(fn), lastname(ln), studentID(ID), occupied(oc) { }

    // data members
    std::string firstname;
    std::string lastname;  
    int studentID;
    int occupied;
};
```

then to read from file and store in `struct student`, you could use `std::vector`, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream> 

int main () {
    // stores all elements created from the reading of the file 
    std::vector<student> class_of_students;

    // attach an input stream
    std::ifstream fin("students.txt");
    // check if file successfully opened 
    if (!fin) std::cerr << "Can't open input file!\n";

    // line of text
    std::string line;

    // read file line by line
    while (getline(fin, line)) {
         // stream to extract data from a line
         std::stringstream ss(line);

         // input variables
         std::string first_name;
         std::string last_name;
         int ID;
         int occupied;

         // example that assumes line format: "f_name l_name ID occ"
         while (ss >> first_name >> last_name >> ID >> occupied) {

             // store one element of type student to the vector
             class_of_students.emplace_back(student(first_name, last_name, ID, occupied));
         }
    }
}
```

More on the use of [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

### Note:

In addition, when you generate a student `ID` you need it to be not only random, but also unique.